# vlc media playing problem

Tags: vlc

It shows..

Required plugin could not be found
Video requires to install plugins to play files of the following types:
1 mpeg-4 aac decoder
2 h.264 decoder

It is show in a alert box.

Say answer like download separate and install.

Answer (score 3):

Install from Ubuntu software.

> Restricted Options for Ubuntu

This is codec pack

>

or
you can install it from terminal if you prefer

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 2):

Install

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```